# flutter doctor with java 14

Tags: flutter

There is an issue with Android sdkmanager where it does not work with Java 14 i using HP AMD Pro A10 cpu

```
    C:\Users\ELDoctor>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

C:\Users\ELDoctor
```

flutter doctor --android-licenses

```
C:\Users\ELDoctor>flutter doctor --android-licenses
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\DEV\SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update



C:\Users\ELDoctor>
```

update sdk path

```
C:\Users\ELDoctor>flutter config --android-sdk C:\DEV\SDK
Setting "android-sdk" value to "C:\DEV\SDK".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.
```

C:\DEV\SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update

```
C:\Users\ELDoctor>flutter config --android-sdk C:\DEV\SDK
Setting "android-sdk" value to "C:\DEV\SDK".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.

C:\Users\ELDoctor>C:\DEV\SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more

C:\Users\ELDoctor>
```

Comment: I think you should replace your jdk with version 8, that's the latest version Android supports

Comment: Fixed after downgrade to JDK 8 thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Android SDK Command-lite Tools**.

Open Android Studio > File > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools, then select Android SDK Command-lite Tools and Apply the changes.[image: Android Studio Settings]